# ValidationException while saving on DynamoDB with mapper

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have this error while saving a new item (`WCode`) into a DynamoDB instance by using `DynamoDBMapper`:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 4OOMKU7NS1VD19EN988SUUM3U7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1369)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:913)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:631)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:400)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:362)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:311)
  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1966)
  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1780)
  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1110)
  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:806)
  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:989)
  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:835)
  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:669)
  at com.wkt.cdmng.MessageAnalyzer.storeCode(MessageAnalyzer.java:220)
  at com.wkt.cdmng.MessageAnalyzer.run(MessageAnalyzer.java:156)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I guest it's something related to the key attributes on the `WCode` class but I can't really understand which one and how to search for additional details problem.

The following is the `WCode` model class and all the attributes names are correctly reported:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBIndexHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;
import java.util.Date;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "CODES_DEV")
public class WCode {
  private String id;
  private String code;
  private String extra;

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "ID")
  public String getId() {return id;}
  public void setId(String code) {id = "0|" + code + "|" + String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());}

  @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "CD-index", attributeName = "CD")
  public String getCode() {return code;}
  public void setCode(String code) {this.code = code;}

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "EX")
  public String getExtra() {return extra;}
  public void setExtra(String extra) {this.extra = extra;}
}
```

This is the method I use to store the item (`storeCode`):

```
private void storeCode(String code) {
  DynamoDBMapper mapper = awsDynamo.getMapper(); // singleton class I use to connect to DynamoDB
  WCode tmpCode = new WCode();
  tmpCode.setId(code);
  tmpCode.setCode(code);
  tmpCode.setExtra("");
  mapper.save(tmpCode);
}
```

I'm using `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb` and `aws-java-sdk-sqs` (the latter for another part of the project) version `1.10.58`.

Does someone can point me to a possible solution or suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you compared the keynames of WCode class with the keynamens in your dynamodb in aws? As I remember they are case sensitive

Comment: You're right; I did, they seem to be corrected.

Comment: No I mean you're right, it's case sensitive. I already checked the names match and there is no difference, they are correct.

Comment: I haven't used the mapper, I'm using my own way over the low level API. But I checked my DynamoDB Table definitions and saw that I use camel case and no hyphens. Possible this is your problem. Because the error is protocol related, your code already send a create request to dynamodb and the result is an error saying a key mismatch, which could only be a mismatch between your table key definitions and used keys in your entity class.

Comment: I use a hypen only in `globalSecondaryIndexName` but that's the name; anyway, I tried to change the specified names of the attributes into this (`id`, `cdIndex`, `cd`, `ex`) but I got the same error; I also tried to change the name of the table to `codesDev` but I obtained the `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Comment: Sorry then it's out off my scope. I never used mapper. Have you tried a low level api test if you can create an item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I've resolved using batchSave function instead of save:

```
mapper.batchSave(Arrays.asList(tmpCode));
```

It worked for me.